# Regarding Chernoff inequality to get the upper bound

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

> Given $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ independent random Bernoulli variables having expected value $\mu$.
> Then Chernoff bound is $P((1/n)*(X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{n}) \le \mu-\epsilon) \le e^{-2*\epsilon^{2}*n}$.

We have $D = 4 * (X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{n})$ and each variable i.e. $X_{i}$ has expected value $\frac{1}{2}$ . Using the above inequality and the given values, the upper bound on the probability of $D<=n$ has to be obtained.

I am unable to find a suitable approach to find the upper bound on the probability of $D<=n$. I plugged the values in the inequality and got it as probability of $D/(4n)≤E[D/(4n)]−ϵ$ but not able to proceed post it. Any hints on how to approach the same?

Comment: I haven't seen this particular formulation of a Chernoff bound, but it looks close enough to what I *have* seen that I'll go along with it. Caveat out of the way: You want to start with $P(D \le n)$ and then rewrite $D$ in terms of the $X_i$. From there, rework the inequality so that the LHS is $\overline{X}$; the RHS will be some expression that you set equal to $\mu - \epsilon$ -- in this case, $n/2 - \epsilon$. Solving for $\epsilon$ will give you the missing piece for the exponent on $e$. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: @dmk thank you i tried solving the epsilon value and got (p-1)/2. On plugging the value, i got the bound but it is coming incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we rewrite the event of interest to conform to the Chernoff bound:

\begin{align}
P(D \le n) &= P\left(4\sum X_i \le n\right) \\
&= P\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum X_i \le 1/4\right). \\
\end{align}

Now, if we set $1/4$ equal to $\mu - \epsilon = \frac{n}{2} - \epsilon$, then $\epsilon = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4}$.  Hence,

\begin{align}
P(D \le n) &= P\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum X_i \le \mu - \left[ \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right] \right) \\
& \le \exp \left(-2\left[\frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right]^2 n \right).
\end{align}

Comment: thank you I tried this but still got the wrong bound

Comment: What is the right bound?

Comment: Not sure. Its not given.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, then, when you say you tried what I wrote but still got it wrong?

Comment: I used the upper bound $\exp \left(-2\left[\frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right]^2 n \right)$ but getting it incorrect in the auto submission

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, it's late. What's the real value of $\mu$?

Comment: no issues $\mu$ is the expected value of Bernoulli random variable

Comment: with $\mu=1/2$ am able to get the answer with the above computation thank you